# IndexToString convertion with labels from StringIndexer

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

How can I convert using `IndexToString` by taking the labels from `labelIndexer`?

```
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="shutdown_reason", outputCol="label")

idx_to_string = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="predictedValue")
```

Answer (score 9):

> How can I convert using IndexToString by taking the labels from labelIndexer?

You cannot. `labelIndexer` is a `StringIndexer`, and to get labels you'll need `StringIndexerModel`. `fit` the model:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("foo", ), ("bar", )
]).toDF("shutdown_reason")

labelIndexerModel = labelIndexer.fit(df)
```

use labels:

```
idx_to_string.setLabels(labelIndexerModel.labels)
idx_to_string.getLabels()
# ['foo', 'bar']
```

and `transform`:

```
df_with_prediction = labelIndexerModel.transform(df).withColumnRenamed(
    "label", "prediction"
)

idx_to_string.transform(df_with_prediction).show()
# +---------------+----------+--------------+
# |shutdown_reason|prediction|predictedValue|
# +---------------+----------+--------------+
# |            foo|       0.0|           foo|
# |            bar|       1.0|           bar|
# +---------------+----------+--------------+
```